# Programmatically detect when a script has been blocked/fails to load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a page which is reliant on some advertising scripts, and if they are blocked the page just totally fails.

I need a way to detect whether or not external scripts successfully loaded -- if not, I'll force the page to continue without them.

Is there a way to do this programmatically? I have no control over the content of the ad scripts so I cant have them set a variable or something. A timeout is my first idea, but that seems messy (what if they just have a slow connection?). Further, listening for events on script elements is not reliable. any clean solutions to this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend that you are displaying a message saying "Something in your browser blocks scripts. Please disable your ad-blockers and enable JavaScript in your browser settings.", and make that message disappear via JavaScript, when a script is loaded.

Comment: @user4970174 I'd love to do that, but unfortunately that's no-bueno with the higher-ups. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A real low tech way would be for each script to put something in the global namespace.  Then you can just check for the existence of that.

E.g.

advertisingScript1.js:

```
advertisingScript1Loaded = true;
...
```

now in your main page you can check to see if the script has loaded with:

```
if (typeof advertisingScript1Loaded !== 'undefined' && advertisingScript1Loaded) {
    // Do something that relies on the script
    ...
}
```

Note if the scripts are set to load asynchronously you will need to have some kind of ready callback before you do the test.

Comment: As stated in the question, I have no control over the content of the ad scripts. so I cant have them set a variable.

Comment: Then look for something the advertising script puts in the global namespace and test that

Comment: Do you have control over the script tag that references the advertising script?

Comment: If so you could use techniques like the ones in this article to detect the script has loaded: https://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/how-to-detect-when-an-external-library-has-loaded

Comment: Ended up going with a modified version of your comment link solution. Thank you.